# Django Admin don't call `_get_FIELD_display`

Tags: django, django-models

I have overridden the `_get_FIELD_display` in my model in it's used correctly in the serializers

however, the Django admin apparently doesn't call it

The model

```
class X(TimeStampedModel):
    STATUSES = Choices(
        ("PENDING", _("Pending")),
        ("PLACED", _("Placed")),
        ("SHIPPED", _("Shipped")),
        ("DELIVERED", _("Delivered")),
    )
    status = FSMField(default=STATUSES.PENDING, choices=STATUSES, protected=True)
    
    def get_status_display(self) -> str:
        """ Overrides to replace Order.STATUSES.DELIVERED with Completed as it's confusing."""
        value = self.status
        if value == Order.STATUSES.DELIVERED:
            return _("Completed!")
        choices_dict = dict(Order.STATUSES)
        # force_str() to coerce lazy strings.
        return force_str(choices_dict[value], strings_only=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't work you can check this method [link](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L891).
and if you read this method there a some comments like this

```
if self.choices is not None:
        # Don't override a get_FOO_display() method defined explicitly on
        # this class, but don't check methods derived from inheritance, to
        # allow overriding inherited choices. For more complex inheritance
        # structures users should override contribute_to_class().
        if "get_%s_display" % self.name not in cls.__dict__:
            setattr(
                cls,
                "get_%s_display" % self.name,
                partialmethod(cls._get_FIELD_display, field=self),
            )
```

so if you want to override this method you should override the ***contribute_to_class*** first of all in the Field you use so simply create a subclass from the *FSMField* and override this method